# Unable to start Terminator in Fedora

Tags: fedora, python, gnome-terminator

I'm not a Unix-friendly user, so my question could be very dummy.
I installed Terminator using this command:

```
sudo dnf install terminator
```

After some days of using without problem, for some reason, today I could not start it properly with this message

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/window.py:62: Warning: The property GtkWindow:allow-shrink is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
  self.set_property('allow-shrink', True)
```

I tried to start it using `sudo`, the message is still there. But I am able to start it.

I cannot always be using `sudo` to start Terminator.

Many thanks for any support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could because the config file is different between root and user make it just be able to start under root.

I viewed this file under normal user

```
~/.config/terminator/config
```

and try to remove this line to make it similar to the one in root

```
use_custom_command = True
```

For those who get the error with key-binding for *hide_window*, try to map it to another key-binding (I choose: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F11) as below:

```
[keybindings]
    hide_window = <Shift><Control><Alt>F11
```